# jQuery file upload check for init before destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using blueimps jQuery file upload plugin and want to destroy all previous instances before creating new ones. The problem is that I get an error when I do something like this

```
$('.upload').each(function(){
  $(this).fileupload('destroy');
  $(this).fileupload({ ... });
});
```

because there are some (new) elements that haven't initialized the plugin yet.
How do I check for them? I can't find anything in the documentation towards that and don't know if there is a "native" way with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to element to indicate that the fileupload plugin is initialized.

```
$('.upload').each(function(){

  if($(this).hasClass('initialised')){
    $(this).fileupload('destroy');
    $(this).removeClass('initialised');
  }

  $(this).fileupload({ ... });
  $(this).addClass('initialised');

});
```

Comment: wow, this is actually so simple that I kinda in doubt about me. Why I havn't thought about it myself?